# Highlight edited row in MVC

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc

I am using MVC razor 5 and trying to highlight row after edit. I've written a script where I highlight a row where I find that it contains some value (Like id = 5, Id field is hidden).

Now the problem is if there is a value in other columns that contains a number which is equal to Id that row is highlighted to.

How can I make it so that only rows column data-field="Id" would be checked?

My code:

```
<script>
$( document ).ready(function() {
    var aset = @Html.Raw(Json.Encode(@ViewBag.CreatedId));
    $('#transport tr td').filter(function() {
        return $(this).text() == aset;
    }).closest('tr').addClass("highlight");
});
</script>
```

`ViewBag.CreatedId` is the Id which I want to highlight.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

like this?:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    var aset = 5; // your ID
    $('#transport tr').each(function(){
        if($('td',this).html()==aset){
            $(this).addClass('highlight');
        }
    });
});
```

[jsfiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/AjtCR/6/)

Comment: http://shrib.com/4X6dYLl8 HTML tr in header class=pazymetas(pazymetas equals to highlight) is set by your javascript.

Comment: u can use $('#transport tbody tr').each(...);